# namespace error when creating a service

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony2 newbie here.

I try to create a service in my application. I followed the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Here is my code:

**file BC/MBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:**

```
---
services:
    metas:
        class: BC\MBundle\Metas\Metas
```

**file BC/MBundle/Metas**

```
<?php
namespace BC\MBundle\Metas;    
class Metas {
    public function queryAllCategories() {
        return array();
    }
}
```

**file BC/MBundle/Controller/AController.php**

```
<?php
namespace BC\MBundle\Controller;
// ...
use BC\MBundle\Metas\MetasController;

class AController extends Controller {
    public function homeAction() {
        return $this->render(
            'tpl.html.twig',
            array(
                'categories' => $this->get('metas')->queryAllCategories(),
             )
        );
    }
}
```

---

The error is:

```
Attempted to load class "Metas" from namespace "BC\MBundle\Metas".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move

   > file BC/MBundle/Metas

   to BC/MBundle/Metas/Metas.php
2. Try to clear cache with

   ```
   php app/console cache:clear
   ```

   or

   ```
   php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
   ```

   for production environment

Comment: the same message is displayed.